# Dividir o separar vector? MATLAB

Tags: matlab

**Hola a todos!**

Tengo la siguiente duda:

Como hago que  un vector en matlab que obtengo de un .dat y con una gran cantidad de valores (mas de 10000). Elimine la primera mitad e ingresarlo en otro vector.

Algo asi: 
v=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10] (lo que tengo)

v'=[6 7 8 9 10] (lo que necesito)

**Gracias!**

Comment: Puedes usar rangos `newv=v(6:10)`

Comment: GRACIASS, me funciono

Answer (score 0):

Con el siguiente código te quedas con la primera mitad de tu vector o con la segunda:

```
v'=v(1:end/2)       % Primera mitad del vector
v''=v(end/2:end)    % Segunda mitad del vector
```

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente código permite realizar lo que deseas:

```
% Introducimos el vector
vector = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

% Calculamos el índice de la mitad del vector
mitad = floor(length(vector) / 2);

% Obtenemos las dos mitades del vector
mitad1 = vector(1:mitad);
mitad2 = vector(mitad+1:end);

% Mostramos las dos mitades del vector en forma de vectores
disp('Primera mitad:');
disp(mitad1);
disp('Segunda mitad:');
disp(mitad2);
```